# Error in pyspark pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am using PySpark `Pipeline` to generate some features.

```py
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[token_q1,token_q2,remover_q1,remover_q2,
                          transformer_textlength_q1,transformer_textlength_q2,transformer_totalwords,
                          transformer_commonwords,transformer_difftwolength,
                          transformer_fuzz_qratio,transformer_fuzz_partial_token_setratio,
                          transformer_fuzz_partial_token_sortratio,transformer_fuzz_token_setratio,
                          transformer_fuzz_token_sortratio,transformer_fuzz_partialratio,transformer_fuzz_wratio,
                          q1w2model,q2w2model,
                          transformer_manhattan, transformer_braycurtis, transformer_canberra,
                          transformer_cosine,transformer_euclidean,
                          transformer_jaccard,transformer_minkowski,transformer_kurtosis_q1,
                          transformer_kurtosis_q2,transformer_skew_q1,transformer_skew_q2,
                          assembler,lr])
```

`lr` is the logistic regression which is the final step in the above pipeline. When I am not using this, I get correct transformations using `pipeline.transform(train)`. The error is

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: init value should <= bound'.

Comment: When I inspected the transformed data. I get some NaN in data. How can we handle then NaN in pipeline.

Comment: You cannot. You have to remove or replace before training.

Comment: @user9613318 but NaN are introduced as part of the pipeline.

Comment: None of transformers is a standard ML code judging from the names. It means that NaNs are introduced by your own code (or maybe some 3rd party code) we don't have access. But the answer is still the same - you have to fix it before you pass data to `lr`.

Comment: @user9613318 yes you are right. I was able to handle the NaN in my transformers.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and resolved with encoding all none or null type values with 0.0. Depending on the use case, it might be best to encode the NaN values with 0.0, replace them with another value, or drop them all together.